# What Does a Pipe Symbol ("|") in a C# String Do?

Tags: c#, string

The following is a sample line of code:

```
fDialog.Filter = "SSIS Package (*.dts, *.dtsx)|*.dts;*.dtsx";
```

What does the pipe symbol do in this string?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation, see if this helps  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog.filter(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: This isn't a question about what it does in C#. It doesn't do anything in this context in C#. This is a question about how file dialogs parse the filters they're given. That's a very different matter.

Comment: It's a separator for multiple filter options

Comment: @MatthewHaugen my bad for the confustion.  This is my first time using the file dialogue and thought maybe this applied to other strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipe you are looking at isn't a language feature. It is a delimiter for the string that tells a dialog box what to put into the drop list that can help the user find files known to your application.

There IS a single-pipe "logical or" in C#, but would not typically be seen outside of bitwise logic.

```
byte byteA = 0;
byte byteB = 1;
long result= byteA | byteB;
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, the pipe symbol denotes an OR. However, in this particular context it's interpreted by the [file dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a separator between descriptions and file name patterns:

```
Description 1|*.ext1|Description 2|*.ext2|...
```

The string is split on the pipe, and then the values are paired up. The first string in the pair is the description displayed to end-users, and the second one is the pattern for the file extension.